# Is polarization a stable state?

Tags: electromagnetism, polarization

Do a polarized light beam stays polarized over large distance or does it kind of relax and eventually become unpolarized?

Comment: Polarized light from astronomical sources (both from stars with strong magnetic fields and from light polarized by galactic matter) has been detected by astronomers, so we know that polarization does not degrade easily. The interesting question is if we can set a low upper bound on how fast it would degrade over cosmological distances. That's a very good question.

Comment: _Do a polarized light beam stays polarized ( **100% up or 100% down** ) over large distance or does it kind of relax and eventually become unpolarized ( **50% up + 50% down** ) ?_ Is it not a trivial question related to the events encountered on the path ? I don't know a theory of the spontaneous spin change. Else please , provide more context.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the material the light beam is traveling through.

If the light is traveling through some media - vacuum, glass, etc. - then its polarization state will remain the same. However, if it is traveling through certain [birefringent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birefringence) materials, then its polarization state may change.

Mathematically, this difference arises from the description of the [permittivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity) of the medium. Generally - in isotropic<sup>1</sup> materials - this is a scalar quantity. However, in materials exhibiting birefringence - anisotropic materials - it is a tensor quantity. Thus, there is a more complex relationship between the electric field and the electric displacement field, leading to a change in polarization of the electromagnetic field.

---

<sup>1 *Isotropy* refers to uniformity in all directions; *anisotropy* refers to some lack of uniformity in a given direction.</sup>